# Convert Time to Time Stamp PHP

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have a string :

```
$Value = 03/25/2014 10:15 AM
```

I would like to convert this to a mysql timestamp.  When I use date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $Value) it does not work.  Can someone please help me convert this?  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` needs a UNIX timestamp:

```
$Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Value));
```

Comment: don't forget quotes around the original time `$Value = "03/25/2014 10:15 AM"`